# GWT Forward Button

Tags: gwt, browser-history

I'm having an issue handling the forward button.
Basically, when a user is on a page and has made changes without saving then presses the backwards or forwards button they are presented with a prompt and two options: Leave or Stay.

I have implemented the backwards button fine, and choosing to stay on the page works well using History.newItem(currentToken) - the back button is still clickable.

However  with the forwards button, if I use History.newItem(currentToken), it brings this to the front of the history stack and the forward button can no longer be clicked.
History.replaceItem(currentToken) causes the same issue.

How do I handle the cancelling of a forwards action so that I stay on my current page, but the forwards button is still enabled?

```
@Override
public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
  logger.info("back button pressed: " + event.getValue());

  String evenVal = event.getValue();
  String token = History.getToken();

  AbstractPresenter presenter = sessionKiosk.getCurrentlyShowingPresenter();
  if (presenter instanceof NSRCommonWorksheetPresenter && sessionKiosk.isDirty()) {
     ((NSRCommonWorksheetPresenter)presenter).setHistoryToken(event.getValue());
     ((NSRCommonWorksheetPresenter)presenter).showUnsavedChangesLeavingPageDialog();
  }
  else {
     handleHistoryEvent(event.getValue());
  }
}
```

The dialog is shown and when I click on stay on page the following is called.

```
public void stayOnCurrentPage() {
  if (eventMap.get(prevPage) != null) {
     History.newItem(prevPage, false);
  }
}
```

Update: Basically history.newItem(value) removes the use of the forward button. Is there another way to cancel the event? If I just do nothing, th page stays where i want but the url still updates

None of the 3 options in the else statement seem to work.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post youor code so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cancel the event without touching History or tokens.

UPDATE:

It appears from your code that you are not intercepting the event (back/forward button), but let it go through, get the new token, and then force a return to the previous state under certain circumstances.

I suggest using [Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) pattern where every "place" within your app has a corresponding "activity". Each activity in your app will implement GWT [Activity](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/activity/shared/Activity.html) interface which includes `mayStop()` method. This method is called *before* a user navigates away from a specific place in your app, giving you an opportunity to warn a user and cancel the navigation if necessary.

In general, this pattern offers a very robust support for the History mechanism, covering many use cases.

If you want to support History mechanism yourself, take a look at [PlaceChangeRequestEvent](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/place/shared/PlaceChangeRequestEvent.html) - it allows you to warn a user who tries to navigate away from a place in your app.

Comment: How do I simply cancel it?

Comment: More info: we're using HandlerManager, not SimpleEventBus.
I've shown the onValueChanged method - does this not intercept the event?